# WinRE.wim [DELETED] folder

Tags: data-recovery, windows-server-2016, system-recovery

I'm recovering a Windows Server 2016 system.

Tracking lost information. I accessed the Windows Recovery partition and copied the WinRE.wim file.  After opening WinRE.wim I can see the traditional code folders (\Windows \Program Files, ...) but also a folder named "[DELETED]" that has a bunch of files named with numbers (183, 596, 1112, ...) this folder has around ~400MB in a ~500MB .wim

What are this files?

What information is stored here from the volumes I am recovering?

What good info can I extract from here?

Comment: Your question is tagged as Windows 10, but you mention Windows 2016, which would indicate you are actually using Windows Server 2016.  So what version of Windows are you actually using?  Please provide this clarification as an edit to your question.  Additionally, it is not clear, what your actual question is exactly.

Comment: the tag for "windows-server-2016" did not exist... and windows 2016 is based in windows 10 (also the recovery environment is the same).... but to abreviate I just create the tag for "windows-server-2016"... ;-)

Comment: The confusion come from calling it "Windows 2016" instead of "Windows Server 2016".

Comment: I attempted to correct the grammatical mistakes, but I did my best, to guess what your actual question is.  Your description of the problem is extremely confusing.